# Which statement is correct about electron orbitals and energy levels?

Tags: homework, atoms, electronic-configuration

> Which statement is correct about electron orbitals and energy levels?
>
> A. Yttrium, $\ce{Y}$ ($Z = 39$) is the first element in the periodic table with an electron in a f sub-level.
>
> B. The maximum number of electrons in one d orbital is 10.
>
> C. The maximum number of electrons in the 4<sup>th</sup> main energy level is 18.
>
> D. In a main energy level, the sub-level with the highest energy is labelled f.

I thought B and D are all possible solutions to this answer.

B--the maximum number of electrons in 1 d orbital is 10.

D--in main energy level, the sub-levels in order of increasing energy is s $<$ p $<$d $<$f

So why is the answer only D?

Please advise and sorry in advance for the wrong tags or title name, as I am new to the group and am trying to improve on it.

Comment: You mixed up a d orbital with the d subshell. One d subshell contains five d orbitals.

Comment: @orthocresol, so for B, the maximum number of electrons in one d orbital should be 2?

Comment: Meowth, that's right!

Comment: If you really want to blow your mind (and, incidentally, prove D as technically sort-of incorrect), [look into](http://www.askamathematician.com/2012/01/q-is-it-possible-for-an-atomic-orbital-to-exist-beyond-the-s-p-f-and-d-orbitals-they-taught-about-in-school-like-could-there-be-a-other-letter-orbital-beyond-that/) g-orbitals, and h-orbitals, and i-orbitals, and ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @orthocresol got this first, and it should be credited to him, I'm posting it as an answer.

In option (B), the statement is incorrect as it refers to $d$ **orbitals**, which can (according to Pauli's Exclusion Principle) hold 2 electrons each, rather than the $d$ subshell, which can hold 10 electrons, as it has a total of 5 $d$ orbitals which can hold 2 electrons each, and $5*2=10$.

Thus, only option (D) is correct.